# Installation of iMod on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, nvidia, gpu, cuda

I'm trying to create a shell script that installs a series of things for me. One such thing is iMod. I've located self-installing shell script for iMod and have run the following commands on my bash console:

```bsh
export IMOD_VERSION=4.11.12
export CUDA_VERSION=10.1
wget https://bio3d.colorado.edu/imod/AMD64-RHEL5/imod_${IMOD_VERSION}_RHEL7-64_CUDA${CUDA_VERSION}.sh
sudo sh imod_${IMOD_VERSION}_RHEL7-64_CUDA${CUDA_VERSION}.sh
```

### Note

The issue still persists after restarting the device and disconnecting and reconnecting to it (via SSH, starting a new terminal)

### Installation Output

```bsh
$ export IMOD_VERSION=4.11.12
$ export CUDA_VERSION=10.1
$ wget https://bio3d.colorado.edu/imod/AMD64-RHEL5/imod_${IMOD_VERSION}_RHEL7-64_CUDA${CUDA_VERSION}.sh
--2022-02-02 03:16:12--  https://bio3d.colorado.edu/imod/AMD64-RHEL5/imod_4.11.12_RHEL7-64_CUDA10.1.sh
Resolving bio3d.colorado.edu (bio3d.colorado.edu)... 128.138.72.88
Connecting to bio3d.colorado.edu (bio3d.colorado.edu)|128.138.72.88|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 205325213 (196M) [application/x-sh]
Saving to: ‘imod_4.11.12_RHEL7-64_CUDA10.1.sh.1’

100%[===================================================================================================================>] 205,325,213 5.60MB/s   in 38s

2022-02-02 03:16:51 (5.21 MB/s) - ‘imod_4.11.12_RHEL7-64_CUDA10.1.sh.1’ saved [205325213/205325213]

$ sudo sh imod_4.11.12_RHEL7-64_CUDA10.1.sh

This script will install IMOD in /usr/local and rename
any previous version, or remove another copy of this version.

It will copy IMOD-linux.csh and IMOD-linux.sh to /etc/profile.d

You can add the option -h to see a full list of options

Enter Y if you want to proceed: y
Extracting imod_4.11.12_RHEL7-64_CUDA10.1.tar.gz ...
Extracting installIMOD
Checking system and package types
Saving the Plugins directory in the existing installation
Removing link to previous version but leaving previous version
Removing an existing copy of the same version...
Unpacking IMOD in /usr/local ...
Linking imod_4.11.12 to IMOD
Restoring the Plugins directory
Copying startup scripts to /etc/profile.d: IMOD-linux.csh IMOD-linux.sh

SELinux is enabled - Trying to change security context of libraries.

The installation of IMOD 4.11.12 is complete.
You may need to start a new terminal window for changes to take effect

If there are version-specific IMOD startup commands in individual user
 startup files (.cshrc, .bashrc, .bash_profile) they should be changed
 or removed.

Cleaning up imod_4.11.12_RHEL7-64_CUDA10.1.tar.gz, installIMOD, and IMODtempDir
```

Comment: I've read your post three times but I can't see the issue you're experiencing. Do you get a warning, an error? What's not working as expected?

Comment: running imod or imodhelp gives the `command not found` error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some time to try and reproduce your problem.

Stock CentOS 7.9 minimal.

Then:

```bsh
export IMOD_VERSION=4.11.12
export CUDA_VERSION=10.1
wget https://bio3d.colorado.edu/imod/AMD64-RHEL5/imod_${IMOD_VERSION}_RHEL7-64_CUDA${CUDA_VERSION}.sh
sudo sh imod_${IMOD_VERSION}_RHEL7-64_CUDA${CUDA_VERSION}.sh
```

Output:

```bsh
This script will install IMOD in /usr/local and rename
any previous version, or remove another copy of this version.

It will copy IMOD-linux.csh and IMOD-linux.sh to /etc/profile.d

You can add the option -h to see a full list of options

Enter Y if you want to proceed: Y
Extracting imod_4.11.12_RHEL7-64_CUDA10.1.tar.gz ...
Extracting installIMOD
Checking system and package types
Unpacking IMOD in /usr/local ...
Linking imod_4.11.12 to IMOD
Copying startup scripts to /etc/profile.d: IMOD-linux.csh IMOD-linux.sh

SELinux is enabled - Trying to change security context of libraries.

The installation of IMOD 4.11.12 is complete.
You may need to start a new terminal window for changes to take effect

If there are version-specific IMOD startup commands in individual user
 startup files (.cshrc, .bashrc, .bash_profile) they should be changed
 or removed.

Cleaning up imod_4.11.12_RHEL7-64_CUDA10.1.tar.gz, installIMOD, and IMODtempDir
```

It appears that the installation script installed software under `/usr/local/IMOD`:

```bsh
[test@centos7test ~]$ ll /usr/local/
total 0
<...>
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root  12 Feb  3 10:31 IMOD -> imod_4.11.12
drwxr-xr-x. 13 1095  111 286 Nov 19 12:32 imod_4.11.12
<...>
```

Now, it's very important to logout and login to your shell, because it needs to pick up the following piece of code that was installed in `/etc/profile.d/IMOD-linux.sh`:

```bsh
<...>
export IMOD_DIR=${IMOD_DIR:=/usr/local/IMOD}

# Put the IMOD programs on the path
#
if ! echo ${PATH} | grep -q "$IMOD_DIR/bin" ; then
    export PATH=$IMOD_DIR/bin:$PATH
fi
<...>
```

This is reflected in your current `$PATH` env var:

```bsh
[test@centos7test ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/IMOD/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

I was now successfully able to locate and run both the `imod` and `imodhelp` binaries:

```bsh
[test@centos7test local]# whereis imod imodhelp
imod: /usr/local/imod_4.11.12/bin/imod
imodhelp: /usr/local/imod_4.11.12/bin/imodhelp
```

If for some reason your machine isn't picking up the file under `/etc/profile.d/IMOD-linux.sh` you can force run it like so:

```bsh
[test@centos7test ~]# source /etc/profile.d/IMOD-linux.sh
```